# Existence of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

V is a vector space over the field F. W is a proper subspace of V. Does there exist a subspace U such that V is the direct sum of U and W. I have been able to prove that such a subspace exists in the finite dimensional case. Can I get a hint on how to proceed in the non-finite dimensional case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed as in the finite dimensional case: extend a basis of $W$ to a basis of $V$.

Comment: how? using zorns lemma?

Comment: @tony, sure. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044388/extending-a-basis-for-a-subspace-of-v-to-create-a-basis-of-v for instance

Comment: Yes. In particular, consider the set of all subspaces $U$ of $V$ containing $W$, paired with a basis $B_U$, with partial order containment consisting of containment of subspaces and containment of basis. Use Zorn's lemma, and show that any maximal element  must be $V$ with a basis, that  is obviously one which extends the basis of $W$.

Comment: thanks. I have understood it now.